# Getting users birthday from facebook

Tags: objective-c, facebook

This is my code but I am unable to get the users birthday I am getting everything except users Birthday Please help to get the users birthday

```js
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
  [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath: @"me"
    parameters: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: @"email,first_name,last_name,picture,birthday,gender,age_range,name"
      forKey: @"fields"
    ]
    HTTPMethod: @"GET"
    completionHandler: ^ (FBRequestConnection * connection, id result, NSError * error) {
      if (!error) {
        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo: self.view animated: YES];

        // result is a dictionary with the user's Facebook data
        userData = (NSDictionary * ) result;
      }
    }
```

Comment: this information in insufficient in case of Facebook sdk. Have you checked the permissions your requesting from the developers dashboard? and unless the user chooses his or her details to be public you will not be able to view the certain data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634221/how-to-retrieve-friends-birthday-using-facebook-sdk-in-ios

Comment: No I want my own user birthday details the I mean current FB user details.sorry I new to IOS

Comment: Did you ask the user for permission to get their birthday?

Comment: yes I did this is the code NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_birthday", @"user_location",@"email",@"user_friends"];
         [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {

Comment: Are you testing as yourself? ie someone with a role in the App. Was the permission accepted by the end user? You can check the user permissions granted using user-id/permissions https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#checking